# Copy and return modified range in a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My scenario is this: i want to write a function which can remove the 3 lowest element from a range, and returns the modified range to be processed in Google Spreadsheets. I'm totally new to Google App scripts, so my very bad code is here:

```
function removeWorse(range, n) {

  var data = [];

  for(var i = 1; i <= range.getNumColumns(); i++) {
    data.push(range.getCell(1, i).getValue());
  }
  data.sort();

  var range2;
  range.copyTo(range2);

  for(var i = data.length - 1; i >=n; i--) {
    range2.getCell(1, i).setValue(data[i]);
    Logger.log(2);
  }

  return range2;

}
```

It gets stuck in line 11: `copyTo` does not exist.

How can i modify this code to actually do my task? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend passing a range to the function as an array of values (so in a spreadsheet cell you would enter eg `=removeWorse(A1:K1;3)`), modifying that range with Javascript, and then returning the modified range. This avoids any get or set calls which are problematic when used in custom functions. It seems as though you are working with a horizontal range, so something like this should work:

```
function removeWorse(values, n) {
  values[0].sort();
  values[0].splice(0, n);
  return values[0].reverse();
}
```

But note that `sort()` used without an argument will return a [lexographic sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (eg 9 will be considered "larger" than 81). You can use a simple function as an argument in `sort()` to address this:

```
function removeWorse(values, n) {
  values[0].sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});
  values[0].splice(0, n);
  return values[0].reverse();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already figured out to use 2 dimensional arrays. But i missed the behavior of the sort function, which is very important in this case, so many thanks for pointing that out. Also thanks for the splice method, too!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `range.copyTo` function expects another Range as a parameter. When you define `range2` above, it is not a Range object.

Comment: Yeah, i figured that out, but how can is solve this problem? :)

Comment: You don't "return the modified range" to the Google spreadsheet. You just modify the range as necessary with `setValue` and the change will show in the spreadsheet. What is it that you want to do exactly? For each row in the range, if n=3, sort the row and remove last 3 elements? Thus in the end each row of your input range will have 3 blank columns at the end?

Comment: No. I want to return to range to be processed with built-in standard functions like SUM. I do not want to modify the original range.

Comment: There isn't a way to return the range from Apps Script. Check out the setFormula family of functions in the Range class: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setFormula . From Apps Script, you can assign whatever formulas for whatever range you want without 'returning the range' to the spreadsheet.